# Default sort versions with papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the paper_trail gem in my Rails 4 application and I want to set a default sort order. papertrail doesn't have a model, only a controller and an initializer.

Where can I put it? Do I have to create a model for it?

```
default_scope order('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I found that I could just use reverse in my each do block.

`versions.reverse.each`

Since I need nothing more complex than that I guess it will do for now.

Comment: If you only have small number of versions this still works, but for larger amounts will be very bad for performance.

Comment: I'm also using limit to only get the latest 10 or so versions, and this method won't work because paper_trail seems to sort by created_at ASC by default.

Comment: This doesn't work with pagination. Dave T' answer does. `versions.reorder(created_at: :desc)`

Answer (score 9):

There's also the reorder command.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder

```
versions.reorder('created_at DESC')
```

It will replace any prior ordering, thus ignoring Papertrail's pre-defined order.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way would be to remove the previous sorting via unscope and then set it however you want:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope

For example:

```
somethings.version.merge(PaperTrail::Version.unscope(:order)).order('created_at DESC')
```

This would give you a proper Query with the right sorting

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about unscope. I will try this out. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

find *version.rb* in paper_trail gem. directory on my computer shown below. add:

```
scope :by_date_desc, lambda { unscope(:order).order('created_at DESC') }
```

*unscope* necessary to remove prior order in chain (thank you maxigs). use your favorite scope name of course. worked for me.

C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\paper_trail-4.0.0.beta2\lib\paper_trail\frameworks\active_record\models\paper_trail\version.rb